# Minimal height of binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I am learning about binary trees. So for n elements minimal height is `h = ceiling(log(n+1)) - 1`, and I get how this is calculated from `n = 2^(h+1) - 1`, but I don't understand why is *ceiling* function used.. I get that for most values of `n`, `log(n+1)` would be real so I have to use function to make it an integer, but why *ceiling* and not *floor*?

Answer (score 2):

Think about the case n = 2. log(3) is between 1 and 2. If we floor, it would come out to 1-1=0, which is incorrect. If we ceiling, we get 2-1=1, which is correct.

If it helps you, you can think about it as needing to round partial levels up to whole levels, because they still count towards the tree's height.